# Django Channels : TypeError( TypeError: ProactorEventLoop is not supported, got: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

Tags: django, django-channels, channel

I was trying to copy the tutorial in Django Channels Documentation. I am using Django 2.2.19 and Channels 2.1.2
But I'm having errors. It says

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", line 61, in __init__
    raise TypeError: ProactorEventLoop is not supported, got: <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
```